# custom rangeValidation

Tags: c#, dataannotations

**Como fazer um range validator onde o Max seja o ano atual + 1 ?**

Estou querendo fazer uma validação em dataannotation em minhas models
quero fazer um range validation de 1950 até ano atual +1
Por padrão não é possível fazer usando o range padrão

```
 [Range(1950, Convert.ToDouble(DateTime.Now.Year+1), ErrorMessage = "O ano deve estar entre {1} e {2}!" )]
```

não é possível inserir uma variável no valor.
Então tentei expandir a classe RangeAttribute.

```
public class StringLengthRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
                public int Min { get; set; }
                public int Max { get; set; }

                public StringLengthRangeAttribute()
                {
                    this.Min = 0;
                    this.Max = DateTime.Now.Year + 1;
                }

                public override bool IsValid(object value)
                {
                    string strValue = value as string;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
                    {
                        int len = strValue.Length;
                        return len >= this.Min && len <= this.Max;
                    }
                    return true;

                }
}
```

Mas no lado cliente ele não fez a validação!.
tentei com o exemplo descrito aqui, e também não funcionou.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843334/data-annotations-how-can-i-replace-range-values-with-web-config-values-in-mvc3?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nessa linha:

```
int len = strValue.Length;
```

Você esta pegando a quantidade de caracteres que faz parte dessa string e não seu valor, logo o seu return faz algo como:

```
return 4 >= 0 && 4 <= 2018;
```

Já que 2017, por exemplo, possui 4 caracteres.
Tente algo como:

```
if (value is int)
{
    return value >= this.Min && value <= this.Max;
}
```

Ficando assim o código final:

```
public class StringLengthRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }

    public StringLengthRangeAttribute()
    {
        this.Min = 0;
        this.Max = DateTime.Now.Year + 1;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        try
        {
            int strValue = Convert.ToInt32(value);
            return strValue >= this.Min && strValue <= this.Max;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Formato inválido");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: editei a sua resposta com o código final, veja se era isso? porém funcionou..valeu

Comment: agora a clausula SE sempre sera verdadeira já que caso eu não consiga fazer a conversão vai estourar uma exceção não tratada, mas resolve o caso sim.